# Jquery Filter table rows by multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, filtering

I am trying to get a filter working for a table.  What I would like is checkboxes to filter (hide) rows based on whether they're checked or not and if the value is present in the table cell.  I have it somewhat working, but it will only sort one of the checkboxes.  Also, if there are multiple values in the table cell being filtered, that row is hidden.  Thoughts?  Thank you in advance for any help.  I'm really struggling with this for some reason!

Here is the code I have been using:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function () {
var showAll = true;
$('tr').not('.first').hide();
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if ($(this)[0].checked) {
        showAll = false;
        var status = $(this).attr('rel');
        var value = $(this).val();            
        $('td.' + 'status' + '[rel="' + value + '"]').parent('tr').show();

    }
});
    if(showAll){
    $('tr').show();
}
});
```

The markup is as follows (please excuse some messiness, its Wordpress)

```
<div class="grants-filter">
<h3 class="filter-title">Filter Scholarships</h3><br/>
<h3>Year of Study:</h3>
<input type="checkbox" name="chx" rel="status" value="Freshman">Freshman
<input type="checkbox" name="chx" rel="status" value="Sophmore">Sophmore
<input type="checkbox" name="chx" rel="status" value="Junior">Junior
<input type="checkbox" name="chx" rel="status" value="Senior">Senior
<br/><br/><h3>Duration:</h3>
<input type="checkbox" rel="duration" value="Summer">Summer
<input type="checkbox" rel="duration" value="Semester">Semester
<input type="checkbox" rel="duration" value="Full Year or More">Full Year or More


</div>  

<div class="grants-listing">


<table border="1" id="table" class="grants-table">
<thead>
<tr class="first">
<th>Title</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Field</th>
<th>Duration</th>
<th>Year of Study</th>
<th>Other</th>
<th>Procedure</th>
<th>URL</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$grargs = array ( 'post_type' => 'scholarship');
$grant_query = new WP_Query( $grargs );
while ( $grant_query -> have_posts() ):
$grant_query -> the_post(); ?>
<tr class="grant-detail">

<td>
<?php the_title(); ?>
</td>
<td><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 25 ); ?></td>
<td class="fields" rel="<?php echo get_field('fields'); ?>"><?php echo the_field('fields'); ?></td>
<td class="duration" rel="<?php echo the_field('desired_duration'); ?>"><?php echo the_field('desired_duration'); ?></td>
<td class="status" rel="<?php echo the_field('year-of-study'); ?>"><?php echo the_field('year-of-study'); ?></td>
<td class="other" rel="<?php echo the_field('other'); ?>"><?php echo the_field('other'); ?></td>
<td class="procedure" rel="<?php echo the_field('procedure'); ?>"><?php echo the_field('procedure'); ?></td>
<td class="url"><a href="<?php echo get_field('url'); ?>"><?php echo get_field('url'); ?></a></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata(); //reset the first query
?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I think you just are calling the first checkbox [0]

```
if ($(this)[0].checked) {
```

call all by inserting someting like

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
           if (this.checked) {
               console.log($(this).val()); 
           }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, here is a simplified version

```js
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
  var showAll = true;
  $('tr').not('.first').hide();
  $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    showAll = false;
    var status = $(this).attr('rel');
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('td.' + 'status' + '[rel="' + value + '"]').parent('tr').show();
  });
  if (showAll) {
    $('tr').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grants-filter">
  <h3 class="filter-title">Filter Scholarships</h3>
  <br/>
  <h3>Year of Study:</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chx" rel="status" value="Freshman">Freshman
  <input type="checkbox" name="chx" rel="status" value="Sophmore">Sophmore
  <input type="checkbox" name="chx" rel="status" value="Junior">Junior
  <input type="checkbox" name="chx" rel="status" value="Senior">Senior
</div>

<div class="grants-listing">


  <table border="1" id="table" class="grants-table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="first">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Fields</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Procedure</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="grant-detail">
        <td>
          Name
        </td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td class="fields" rel="Freshman">Freshman</td>
        <td class="status" rel="Freshman">Freshman</td>
        <td class="procedure" rel="Freshman">Freshman</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="grant-detail">
        <td>
          Name
        </td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td class="fields" rel="Sophmore">Sopho</td>
        <td class="status" rel="Sophmore">Sopho</td>
        <td class="procedure" rel="Sophmore">Sopho</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="grant-detail">
        <td>
          Name
        </td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td class="fields" rel="Junior">Junior</td>
        <td class="status" rel="Junior">Junior</td>
        <td class="procedure" rel="Junior">Junior</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!  The issue I'm having is that some td's in the table will have multiple values (freshman, sophmore, and Junior) for example.  Selecting Sophmore, for example, will not display rows with multiple values, even if sophmore is one of the values.  Thoughts?

Comment: Any thoughts on how to get the filter to recognize if the value exists within multiple values in a td?

Comment: I'm sorry I am unable to get your point, can you provide a sample output html (not the one with php), what does multiple values in a td mean? Would it be like `<td class="status" rel="Freshman, Sophomore">Freshman, Sophomore</td>`?